# InvokeScript not working properly

Tags: c#

I'm using WebBrowser to load a page. After it finishes , i'm calling an ajax on that page, but my code doesn't wait for that ajax call to finish ; Here's the code:

```
Thread thread2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            browser.Navigate("http://localhost/testpdf.html");
            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }
            var d = browser.Document.InvokeScript("$.ajax({type: 'GET', async:false,url: 'http://localhost/test2.html',complete: function (data) {                     $('body').html(d) } }); return $('body').html()"); //ajax
        });
        thread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread2.Start();
        thread2.Join();
```

d is always null

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Comment: according to the documentation it should return the value of that javascript function

Comment: By the time the JavaScript funtion returns, the `complete` callback has not been executed yet. So the body may as well be empty, which would result in a `null` return value.

Comment: In the example i sent async : false, which means that the return will only happen after the ajax call finishes

Comment: Oh, you're right. But I guess you mean `data` instead of `d` in the callback function!?

Comment: Yes Data . But same result , what i sent is just a dummy code but similar to what i have. The idea is the same.As if the invokeScript doesnt wait for the ajax to complete

Comment: you could wrap your script inside a function() and return from inside the function, now you are executing 2 separate statements, but the return doesn't have a context, IMO

Answer (score 0):

When you call `InvokeScript`, it is intended to execute a function that is already defined in the page's JavaScript.  In your case, you are intending to provide new JavaScript, and then invoke it.  In order for this to work you either need to define the JavaScript as a function in the page, and then invoke it, or use a built-in function (`eval`) to execute the code for you.  This is called "script injection" and is the technique you want to use here.  Try `eval` in this case, like so:

```
string scriptToRun = "$.ajax({type: 'GET', async:false,url: 'http://localhost/test2.html', success: function (data) { $('body').html(data); }, complete: function () {} }); $('body').html();"; //ajax
var d = browser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new Object[] { scriptToRun});
```

Note that I do not "return" the result but rather just list it as the last command, since this is not a function but rather a script to be evaluated.  Also note that you want to use a `success` handler in the `$.ajax` call, since that is the handler that will get the result.  Look at the documentation for jQuery `ajax` and you will see that `complete` does not get the parameters you are expecting, although you can include a `complete` handler if you want to track the status.

Comment: Since Javascript sometimes has different ways of implementation. Any idea what is the browser used by c# in this case?

Comment: it's a wrapped version of Internet explorer

Comment: One last question regarding this issue , any idea why sometimes the js functions throw an undefined error when called from c# level

Comment: Ok here  it goes ,i tried everything . no js files , nothing.i wrote a simple html file, i called that file using webbrowser in c# . And when there's 1 js function it works but when the size of the javascript is big . It gives me that the function is null. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry pedrov, there were a couple typos in my code sample.  It has been fixed above.  Make sure that jquery is included in your source HTML file otherwise this won't work.  If you can provide your samples for testpdf.html and test2.html it might help as well.

Comment: Hello Matthew, The problem is not in the ajax anymore. I'm sorry i'm not able to post my code but i'll try my best to explain my problem.I want to get a pdf file and show it to the user but without showing him the actual directory. So i decided to use pdf.js plugin. So , i'm trying to call the initialization of pdf.js from C#. The problem is that it only renders after returning the actual html string to the page and not on c# side. hope its clear

Comment: Here's an example of the c# code :browser2.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { "try{PDFViewerApplication.initialize().then(webViewerInitialized);} catch(error){$('body').text(error.message)}" });

Comment: Can you use "eval" instead of "execScript"?  execScript always returns null.

Comment: Also, make sure your JavaScript actually evaluates to something.  Otherwise eval won't return anything either.  Looks like you are calling an asynchronous API here (PDFViewerApplication.initialize()) and so the result of your javascript statements won't have a value yet.  You will have to rewrite your javascript to return a result synchronously in order to get that value from c#, either that or stash the value somewhere (e.g. $('body').text) and then make another call to InvokeScript later to get that value.

Comment: I don't care much about the returned value , i want to manipulate the content of the page since the webbrowser is not executing the js commands until the page is loaded in an actual browser. But in all cases i tried your way , but i always get that the function is undefined as if the js libraries are not included in the page

Comment: Is jQuery included in Script tag in the source HTML file?

Comment: Yes everything is included , i even tried the script from firebug console and its works like a charm , but for some reason webbrowser is just not working as its supposed to .